# Creating a proper MultipartBuilder Http Request with OKHttp

Tags: android, multipartform-data, okhttp

ild like to recode my project and use okHttp instead of the default HttpClient implemented in Android.

I've downloaded the latest source of the okhttp-main release.

Now ive found some examples how to create and build a POST Request.

Now my Problem. I want to create a RequestBody which keep several Data (Strings, Files, whatever) but i can't assign them directly.

Means that the RequestBuilder must go through different Loops where it get it's data added.

OkHTTPs RequestBody seems to need the data immediatly as listed in the example
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

When i want to try something like

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);

for (Object aMData : dataClass.getData().entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) aMData;
            String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
            String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();
            requestBody.addPart(keyValue, value);
}


for (DataPackage dataPackage : dataClass.getDataPackages()) {
            requestBody.addPart("upfile[]", dataPackage.getFile());
}

requestBody.build();
```

it fails because build()  itself create the RequestBody. Before it's just a MultipartBuilder(). If i try to force the type to RequestBody it wont compile/run.

So, what is the proper way adding thos data after creating a MultiPartBuilder and add DATA and Strings?

Comment: I've figured out that i can create a RequestBody (for example) called RequestBody requestBodyMain; and add several RequestBodys. For example creating one RequestBody which keep all those Strings to send. And one which keep those files. And at the end create the requestBodyMain which get those other requestbodys added. But how could i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Uploading file in multipart using OkHttp

```
private static final String IMGUR_CLIENT_ID = "...";
private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
  // Use the imgur image upload API as documented at https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image
  RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
      .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
      .addPart(
          Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"title\""),
          RequestBody.create(null, "Square Logo"))
      .addPart(
          Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"image\""),
          RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File("website/static/logo-square.png")))
      .build();

  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .header("Authorization", "Client-ID " + IMGUR_CLIENT_ID)
      .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image")
      .post(requestBody)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

  System.out.println(response.body().string());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me using okHttp3:

```
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            File file = new File(payload);

            RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("file", "image.jpg",
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), file))

                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(formBody).build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
```

Comment: I have implemented it but in my code the data is being posted twice , any solutions please ?

Answer (score 2):

I modified [Dr. Enemy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033493/2877364):

```
 MultipartBody.Builder builder =new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

for (Object aMData : dataClass.getData().entrySet()) {
        Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) aMData;
        String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
        String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();
        builder.addPart(keyValue, value);
}

for (DataPackage dataPackage : dataClass.getDataPackages()) {
        builder.addPart("upfile[]", dataPackage.getFile());
}
```

Start adding the formDataPart to builder and at end create RequestBody

```
RequestBody requestBody = builder.build();
```

you can perform above actions with

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing!  This appears to be a copy of [Dr. Enemy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033493/2877364), except for the `compile` statement.  If that statement is indeed all you added, please leave a comment on the existing answer rather than posting a new answer.  Thanks!

Comment: oh yes sorry I missed it and builder doesn't have 
.type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);

so keep 
.setType((MultipartBuilder.FORM);